# How to receive the error in the onError call back if i have exponential back off using retryWhen

Tags: android, performance, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2

I am using retrofit 2 with rxjava and i implemented an exponential back off using the retry when function, but when the request fails, i dont receive an error in the onError callback, but i receive onCompleted right away.

How can i receive the error in the onError callback ?

Here is my code:

```
mRestApi.getObject(url)
            .retryWhen(attempts -> attempts.zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), (n, i) -> i)
                    .flatMap(i -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "delay retry by " + i + " second(s)");
                        return Observable.timer(i, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the `doOnError` operator e.g.

```
mRestApi.getObject(url)
        .doOnError(e -> System.out.println(e.getMessage()))
            .retryWhen(attempts -> attempts.zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), (n, i) -> i)
                    .flatMap(i -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "delay retry by " + i + " second(s)");
                        return Observable.timer(i, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    }));
```

Comment: Errors are terminal once they reach your subscriber. That's the [Observable contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html).